# Changing current task.json and launch.json to switch to clang++ for c++ in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, clang++

This is my current task.json file

```
{
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
          "-g",
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "g++ build & run active file",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
          "${file}",
          "-o",
          "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
          "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin"
        }
      }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
  }
```

And this is my current launch.json file:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false, //set to true to see output in cmd instead
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
        },
        {
            "name": "g++ build & run active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true, //set to true to see output in cmd instead
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "g++ build & run active file"
        }
    ]
}
```

What are the least changes i need to do to them to be able to compile and debug for c++?

I've tried changing the directory and followed some online guides, but they all got different error to another.

I've ran through command promt and made sure that i had clang++ installed.

Note: Both of these .json files are made by following an online guide. So if it's needed to completely rewrite both of them, I don't mind it.

Comment: I have edited the post. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: change `g++` to `clang++`?

Comment: I meant as in switching the compiler. I have both GDB and Clang installed. But vscode use g++ to compile my c++ code instead.

Comment: yep, change `g++` in your `tasks.json` to `clang++`, vscode is doing exactly what you've asked it to

Comment: I've tried that, but it got me the error "Could not find the task 'g++.exe build active file'".
I also tried changing `g++` to `clang++` in launch.json but it gave me a different error as well. This time about something of linker.

Comment: Sounds like you've changed the name of the task which needs to match the name of the task in `preLaunchTask` in `launch.json`, you need to change the compiler path in `command` instead